# clojure.java.shell/sh gives different behavior than from command line?

Tags: shell, clojure

i'm using clojure to make shell calls of a program (https://github.com/kahypar) but the same call i can successfully make from command line is not working when invoked this way.
the command line is this

```
kahypar -k 2 -e 0.03 -m direct -o cut -w true -p .../baseConfig-direct.ini -h .../g0.hgr
```

I create this command in clojure and use `clojure.java.shell/sh` (via Java's `Runtime.exec()`) like this:

```
(let [khpPath ".../git/kahypar/build/kahypar/application/KaHyPar"
      param (format "-k 2 -e 0.03 -m direct -o cut -w true -p %s -h %s" configFile hgrFile)
      rv (shell/sh khpPath param) ]
```

i get the following error kahypar/boost:

```
khpEval: exit=134 err=libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::wrapexcept<boost::program_options::invalid_option_value>: the argument (' 2 -e 0.03 -m direct -o cut -w true -p .../baseConfig-direct.ini -h .../g0.hgr') for option '--blocks' is invalid
```

but if i replace the call to kahypar with a call to this simple echoArgs.sh script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "echo:"
echo "$@"
echo "printf"
printf '%s\n' "$*"
```

and replace `khpPath` with `echoPath` pointing to this script,
it echos EXACTLY THE SAME ARGUMENTS as on the command line:

```
echo:
-k 2 -e 0.03 -m direct -o cut -w true -p ...baseConfig-direct.ini -h .../g0.hgr
printf
-k 2 -e 0.03 -m direct -o cut -w true -p ...baseConfig-direct.ini -h .../g0.hgr
```

i've also tried experiments passing the multiple arguments individually rather than as part of a single string; still no love.

because `(shell/sh)` uses futures i can't dig into the call stack to trace more deeply.  is there anyway to see where clojure call of shell differs from standard command line?

Comment: How exactly do you call the `sh` function? Please update your question to show that.

Comment: It's supposed to be `(sh "kahypar" "-k" "2" ...)` -- or `(sh "sh" "-c" "kahybar -k 2 ...")`

Comment: @EugenePakhomov, i updated my question with these details.

Comment: @cfrick i updated to mention that i've also tried breaking the single parameter string into bits as you suggest

Comment: @cfrick  BUT your explicit `(sh "sh" "-c" ...)` trick works!  can you make this an answer so i can credit you, with any ideas you have as to why this works!?  thanks in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clojure.java.shell/sh` expects all arguments for the process to run as
*separate* arguments. Your code passes *all* arguments as a single
argument and therefor you get the error about the wrong argument.

So the correct call should look like this:

```clj
(sh "KaHyPar" "-k" "2" "-e" "0.03" "-m" "direct" "-o" "cut" "-w" "true" "-p" configFile  "-h" hgrFile)
```

In cases where so many args are used or the command is already provided
from somewhere else (e.g. user input or config file), parsing it by
(UNIX) "shell rules" and split it like that might be tedious.  In that case, or
when you need (UNIX) "shell-ism" you can also run it via the (UNIX) shell:

```
(sh "/bin/sh" "-c" "KaHyPar -k 2 -e 0.03 -m direct ...")
```

This way the argument can follow shell-rules.

Comment: a remaining question for me is why the call to `kahypar` resulted in such different behaviors, when the `echoArgs` script saw the arguments as intended?

Comment: @rikb Because your echoArgs script is flawed and can not show the problem: try `./echoArgs.sh x 'a b c'` vs `./echoArgs.sh x a b c`